# SQL Procedure failing due to Conversion of Varchar To DateTime error

Tags: sql, vb.net

Im having an issue with a Stored Procedure I have written, I can call it in management studio and it works fine, yet calling it from my codebehind gives this error `The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.` when i call da.Fill(dt)

What is really puzzling me here is that I dont actually convert anything from varchar to datetime, the most I do with the date variables is format them into a different datetime format.

My VB.Net code

```
  Private Function dbGetEvents(ByVal start As DateTime, ByVal days As Integer) As DataTable
      Dim dt As New DataTable()

      Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Blueprint").ToString())

      Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
      cmd.CommandText = "spGetEventDetails"
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start)
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", start.AddDays(days))
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", ddlUser.SelectedValue)

      cmd.Connection = conn

      Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
         conn.Open()
         da.Fill(dt)
         conn.Close()
      End Using

      Return dt
   End Function
```

My SQL Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEventDetails
(
    @start AS DATETIME,
    @end AS DATETIME,
    @userid AS INT
)
AS
BEGIN

SET @start = CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(@start AS DATETIME), 23)
SET @end = CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(@end AS DATETIME), 23)

    -- GET DETAILS FOR TICKETS
    SELECT
        [ev].[id]                           AS [EventID],
        CAST([tck].[TicketID] AS NVARCHAR)  AS [TicketID],
        [tck].[Description]                 AS [Description],
        [ev].[eventstart]                   AS [Start],
        [ev].[eventend]                     AS [End],
        [ev].[status]                       AS [Status],
        [ev].[type]                         AS [EventType],
        CAST([tck].[Type] AS NVARCHAR)      AS [Type],
        CAST([tck].[Product] AS NVARCHAR)   AS [Product],
        CAST([tck].[Severity] AS NVARCHAR)  AS [Severity],
        [ev].[resource_id]                  AS [resource_id],
        CAST(pers.FirstName AS NVARCHAR)    AS [FirstName],
        CAST(pers.Surname AS NVARCHAR)      AS [Surname],
        CAST(tck.LogDate AS NVARCHAR)       AS [LogDate]
    FROM
        tblSupportEvent ev
    JOIN
        tblTicketsInEvents tie
    ON
        ev.id =tie.eventID
    JOIN
        SupportTicketsTbl tck
    ON
        tie.ticketID = tck.TicketID 
    JOIN 
        PersonnelTbl pers
    ON
        pers.ID = tck.LoggedBy 
    WHERE
        ev.type = 1
    AND 
        NOT (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))  
    AND  
        resource_id <> 0  
    AND   
        ev.resource_id = @userid  

UNION 
    -- GET THE DETAILS FOR NON TICKET ITEMS

    SELECT
        [ev].[id]           AS [EventID],
        ''                  AS [TicketID],
        [nti].[Description] AS [Description],
        [ev].[eventstart]   AS [Start],
        [ev].[eventend]     AS [End],
        [ev].[status]       AS [Status],
        [ev].[type]         AS [EventType],
        ''                  AS [Type],
        ''                  AS [Product],
        ''                  AS [Severity],
        [ev].[resource_id]  AS [resource_id],
        ''                  AS [FirstName],
        ''                  AS [Surname],
        ''                  AS [LogDate]
    FROM
        tblSupportEvent ev
    JOIN
        tblNonTicketsInEvents nte
    ON
        ev.id = nte.eventID 
    JOIN
        tblNonTicketItems nti
    ON
        nte.nonTicketID = nti.id    
    WHERE
        ev.type = 2
    AND
        NOT (([eventend] <= @start) OR ([eventstart] >= @end))  
    AND  
        resource_id <> 0  
    AND   
        ev.resource_id = @userid  
END
```

I cant see where this error could be coming from, having tested running it in SQL management studio without error I am pretty sure the error is in the VB.

My first thought was that maybe the parameter I am passing in the @start / @end values arent being recognised as DateTime so I tried adding the parameters like:

```
 Dim p As New SqlParameter

  p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime
  p.ParameterName = "@start"
  p.Value = start
  cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
```

but this just gives me the same result. If anyone can suggest where I am going wrong id be gratefull.

Thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of `eventend` and `eventstart`?

Comment: eventend and eventstart are both DATETIME, this is what is confusing me, if i can run the query in management studio then I would assume the query is correct and it is the VB, but the VB has the correct datatypes too

Comment: Not your problem, but sp stands for system procedure, and should only be used by the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language of the logins is probably different.

```
set dateformat mdy

declare @start datetime = '20110130'

SET @start = CONVERT(CHAR(10), CAST(@start AS DATETIME), 23)
```

Works. But `set dateformat dmy` doesn't.

To extract the `date` part of a `datetime` you can use `DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@start),0)`